# How to display HTML in WPF without Browser?

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I‘ve tried to Display simple HTML formats in WPF.

In Java, you can use simple Components like Label to do this:

```
Label test = new Label(‘<b>Bold</b> Text‘);
```

But how i can do this in C#/WPF **WITHOUT** using WebBrowser components? I don‘t want to use Webbrowser because it will create some overhead if youre using thousands of elements with a full browser engine.

I hope, you can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't without using any third-party software.

Except for the web browser control(s), there is no other HTML parser built-in into the framework.

So you will either have to use a web browser control of some kind or translate your HTML code to `Inline` elements to be displayed in a `TextBlock`, or to RTF text that can be displayed using a `RichTextBox`.

Answer (score -2):

It's a long way from supporting full HTML, but I've written an enhanced TextBlock control that supports basic HTML style formatting tags.

```
/// <summary>
/// An extended TextBlock class, that will take account of formatting tags (similar to Html tags) within the text. 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Supported tags
///     <b>     bold
///     <u>     underline
///     <i>     italic
///     <fs>    font size      use * to indicate a value relative to the current font size
///     <ff>    font family
///     <fg>    foreground     } supports named colours, #RRGGBB & #AARRGGBB formats
///     <bg>    background     }
///     <sub>   subscript
///     <sup>   superscript
///     <lb>    line-break
///     <lt>    <
///     <gt>    >
///     <sl>    /
/// </remarks>
```

The source code is just a little too big for the 30K post limit, but it's available from [Github](https://github.com/Peregrine66/PeregrinesView/blob/master/library/Peregrine.WPF.View/Controls/perFormattedTextBlock.cs).

Mode details on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-controls-formatted-textblock/).